# Is the desktop tag meaningful?

Tags: discussion, tags

A **desktop** tag showed up today, in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/499/work-planning-and-time-protocolling-tool-preferably-with-invoice-generator).
I don't think it contributes much (if at all).
The **linux** tag, also on the question, tells us what we need to know.
Anything that works on a linux desktop will work on a linux laptop.
The possible exception  that it might not be suitable for a linux tablet (because touch screen accessibility), but that should be indicated with a **touch screen** tag

That I think the desktop tag is bad, and warrants paying attention to.
I'm not saying black list it now, but we should be aware of what it is doing.

Comment: I think I agree, though maybe “desktop” was meant as in “desktop environment” or “GUI widget”. I don't know what's a good tag name for that, what does [su] use?

Comment: I was mulling over the same thing, and "desktop" vs "mobile" tags. I think that I agree; these tags are unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit** Comments suggested `desktop-client` as alternative which I suggest we should use. **/Edit**

I wanted to express that it must run as a regular program on my desktop PC.

As in: Not mobile, Not a webapp. I want to have a window.

It's not meant as desktop vs. laptop (as my laptop is my desktop PC and I haven't heard anybody distinguishing them in the last 5 years or so).

For that reason, I want to have the tag and consider it meaningful, I'm very open to better alternatives if desktop is misleading.

Comment: Perhaps (if we can't come up with a better tag), a good tag wiki would do

Comment: But you can't create a [stuff Angelo wants] tag. I'm joking, but see why it is really not advisable to create these broad, sweeping tags to divvy up the site like that — http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/156/tags-for-toolkits/162#162

Comment: How about `desktop-app` or `desktop-client`?

Comment: @allquixotic I like `desktop-client` would you add that as an answer?

Comment: @RobertCartaino I use the tag because I think its meaningful to more then myself. When I wrote the question I asked myself what categories would be useful for future searchers but still not too narrow. (Like 'time-protocoller' would be too narrow) For many users the distinction between "in the web" and "on my desktop" is very important and when I search for a software this is one of the elemental requirements. - I agree that "desktop" is maybe not the best word for it and support alternatives.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Also, without ever reading the meta qustion you linked before, I thought about using `xfce` tag or requirement but refrained from it (and that was a good idea, the answer I got is gnome but looks useful!)

Comment: I personally like `desktop-app`, but `desktop-client` works too.

Comment: Perhaps `non-web-app`

Comment: @Oxinabox No. That would include mobile apps. Also anti-tags seem like a bad idea.